# Getting all contacts with at least one eMail-Address (DISTINCT)

Tags: android, android-contacts, contactscontract, android-cursor

I'm writing a ContactPickerDialog for a custom Preference.

Depending on the preference the ContactPickerDialog should show all contacts with at least one phone number or all contacts with at least one eMail-address. No contact should be shown twice, no matter how many phone-numbers or eMail-addresses are connected with this contact.

I have no problem with getting all contacts with at least one phone-number as I can use `HAS_PHONE_NUMBER` in the where-clause. But I have no idea how to get the contacts with at least one eMail-address without getting some contacts multiple times if they have more than one eMail-address.

This is my code:

```
public void LoadContactsWithTarget(Context context, PickContactDialog.PickTarget pickTarget)
{
    try
    {
        String[] projection = new String[] 
        {
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI,
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID
        };

    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC";

    Uri uri = null;
    String where = "";
    if (pickTarget == PickTarget.PHONE_NR)
    {
        // works great, I only get one contact, no matter how many phone-numbers are connected with this contact
        uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
        where = ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = 1";
    }
    else if (pickTarget == PickTarget.EMAIL)
    {
        // I get one contact/entry for each eMail-address that is connected with the contact but I only want to get one contact, no matter how many eMail-addresse are connected with the contact
        uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI;
        where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA + " NOT LIKE ''";               
    }

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, where, null, sortOrder);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        int iNameColumn      = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
        int iThumbnailColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);
        int iImageColumn     = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI);              
        int iIDColumn        = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) 
        {
            Contact contact = new Contact(cursor.getInt(iIDColumn),
                                          cursor.getString(iNameColumn),
                                          cursor.getString(iThumbnailColumn),
                                          cursor.getString(iImageColumn));

            _lstContacts.add(contact);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }

    cursor.close();
}
catch(Exception e) { }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated

Comment: Have u figured it out ? I am having similar issue

Answer (score 0):

```
            cursorContacts = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                                 ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                 ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                                 ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1},
                    "("+ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?"
                       +" OR "+ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data.MIMETYPE + "=?)"
                    +" AND "+ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                            +" IN (SELECT "+ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID
                                  +" FROM view_data"
                                    +" WHERE "+ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE+"=?"
                                              +" AND "+ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1+" NOT NULL"
                                              +" AND "+ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.DATA1+" NOT LIKE ''"
                            +")"
                    ,
                    new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                 ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                 },
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
```